# Using notepad++ to change format of textline

Tags: text, replace, notepad++

I have a text file like this:

`text  something@mail.com
text2  something2@mail.com`

i have multiple lines in this format and i want to replace it like this:

`something@mail.com:text
something2@mail.com:text2`

I've been trying everything,but it looks like i cant get it work.

Comment: If you've *been trying everything*, you should have at least one or two things you can demonstrate you tried that didn't work for you.

Comment: If you tried everything, that would have necessarily included the correct solution.

Comment: @Poldie well,i didnt pronounce it correct,i meant that i have tried many times,but i couldnt get the result i want

Answer (score 0):

Search > Replace...

Search Mode: `Regular expression`

Find What: `^ *([^ ]+) +([^ ]+)$`

Replace With: `\2:\1`